# ogmailing list + mailgun, getting error: PHPMailer error: Invalid address

Tags: 7, organic-groups, emails, domain-access

Organic Groups - 7.x-2.6
Drupal 7.26
OG Mailinglist - 7.x-1.1-alpha2
Domain Access - 7.x-3.11

Hello, I am attempting to get Organic Groups configured with OG Mailinglist.
I am trying to set OG Mailinglist up to use MailGun. I have a local copy of drupal running on my dev machine.

When I try and configure it all and send a message by creating a new Group posting I get this error:
    PHPMailer error: Invalid address: @smtp.mailgun.org

OG Mailinglist comes with a submodule for MailGun, but there I didn't find any documentation on it.
Despite the fact that I did not find any documentation I gave a go at configuring.

Here is the OG Mailinglist configuration page. I got the smtp.mailgun.org from my mailgun account page. The Message validation string was already there and I did not change it.

[image]

Here are the mailgun settings for OG Mailinglist. I obtained the configuration info again from my MailGun account page.
[image]

These are my MailGun account pages. I obtained all of the configuration info for Drupal OG Mailinglist from these 2 pages.
[image]

[image]

The PHPMailer error does not show up in the reports section until after I try and create a new posting content. It then tries to send the mail to each person in the group, which fails.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks a mizzillion!!!